# R :Error in get.current.chob() : improperly set or missing graphics device

Tags: r

I have downloaded a time series data in to R studio. I have converted the data in to a XTS object using > xts_data <- as.xts(ts_data).Have downloaded library(Quantmod).I try to run the indicator:> addADX(n = 14, maType="EMA", wilder=TRUE).R throws an error:Error in get.current.chob() : improperly set or missing graphics device
I have assigned "windows"to "Backend" and default to "Antialiasing" in the Graphic settings.
I ran dev.off().
I get an :Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device).
I do not understand this (system) message.
Please guide me here.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page  and as indicated there provide a reproducible example including all inputs and library statements.